# Bluetooth is disabled on ubuntu 16.04 and can't be enabled

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth

I want to add a new Bluetooth device. But it seems like Bluetooth is disabled and nothing helps add a new device.

My system: ThinkPad T470s; Ubuntu 16.04 LTS; encrypted Hard drive (I tried it before with a non encrypted HDD and it would work fine). After I setup the system I also updated it and then restart. Now I wanted to connect a bluetooth keyboard.

Results of `rfkill list`:

```
2: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
18: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

So, I assume a Bluetooth adapter exists.

When I go to the bluetooth hardware in the system settings:

[image]

... and try to turn bluetooth on, then you can see (at the top right corner) the Bluetooth icon disappears (for some reasons):

[image]

I tried to reinstall `bluez` and also install `blueman`.

When I open the Bluetooth manager, you can see that none of the icons are clickable.

[image]

I also did this:

`sudo gedit /etc/rc.local`

and added the following line before `exit 0`

> rfkill unblock bluetooth

...and then restart. Then I repeated the steps mentioned above. Same result: Cannot add new devices.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue` terminal command.

Comment: Due to  your hint I could solve it. Thanks @Pilot6 See answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `ibt-12-16.sfi` was missing. I downloaded it from [this site](https://github.com/wkennington/linux-firmware/blob/master/intel/ibt-12-16.sfi) and copied it to `/lib/firmware/intel`

Comment: I see `ibt-12-16.sfi` in the mentioned directory location, but my visibility is still disabled any ideas?